# Como renderizar duas Views tipadas em uma Index()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Estou tentando renderizar duas *views* criadas com o *scaffolding*, uma é para o *Create* e outra é para o *List*.

A ideia é juntar na *index* o seguinte:

```
@model BraveryBranded.ASP.Models.News

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@RenderPage("~/Areas/Admin/Views/News/New.cshtml")
<hr/>
@RenderPage("~/Areas/Admin/Views/News/List.cshtml")
```

Esta gerando um erro falando sobre os *models*. Segue abaixo o print:

[image]

Esta é a minha *List*:

```
@model IEnumerable<BraveryBranded.ASP.Models.News>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Lista";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IDNews)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PostDate)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IDNews)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

E esta é minha *Create*:

```
@model BraveryBranded.ASP.Models.News

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Adicionar";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>News</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IDNews)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IDNews)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IDNews)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PostDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostDate)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Código do *Controller News*:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult List()
{
    var list = UpdateList();
    return View(list);
}

public ActionResult New()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Luiz, se você acessa as páginas independentes (create e lis) elas funcionam? Você poderia colar o código da action dessa página nova que você criou?

Comment: @AndreCalil pior é que não estão funcionando!

Comment: Acho que o Create está com erro, porque a mensagem de erro fala de lista. Você pode adicionar o código de cada action também?

Comment: @AndreCalil Eu não terminei as actions, porém, era para aparecer vazio, pois realmente as listas são vazias, era para aparecer o html delas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luiz, eu *acho* que você não quer o `RenderView`, mas sim o `RenderAction`. Vou assumir isto na minha resposta, se eu estiver errado me diga, ok?

O `RenderView` vai tentar apenas trazer o código daquela view para onde ele foi chamado. Ele não passará pela action equivalente, e é por isso que eu acho que não é a sua intenção. O `RenderAction`, por outro lado, vai executar a action e todo o código que estiver dentro dela, para só então te dar o HTML resultante.

Apenas essa alteração é fácil de fazer, veja:

```
@{
    Html.RenderAction("New", "SeuController");
    Html.RenderAction("List", "SeuController");
}
```

**Porém**, fazer apenas isso pode trazer um resultado indesejado. Se o seu projeto tiver um arquivo de layout, cada página será carregada por completo, o que vai quebrar o seu design. Qual seria uma solução interessante? Poder carregar cada página sozinha ou todas nessa página única. Para isso, vamos alterar as actions, assim:

```
public ActionResult List(bool partial = false)
{
    var list = UpdateList();

    if(partial)
        return PartialView(list);
    else
        return View(list);
}
```

E a chamada nós alteramos para

```
@{
    Html.RenderAction("New", "SeuController", new { partial = true });
    Html.RenderAction("List", "SeuController", new { partial = true });
}
```

Ficou claro? Ao forçarmos que o retorno seja `PartialView`, ele não carregará o HTML do layout, apenas o que foi gerado na página. E como utilizamos um atributo opcional, as chamadas usuais não serão afetadas.

Comment: Cara, funcionou de cara! Muito obrigado, não precisei nem validar a View!

Comment: @LuizNegrini Maravilha, fico feliz em ajudar. Obrigado pelo feedback

Comment: apesar de ter funcionado, minhas validações com os helpers nos models pararam de funcionar. O que ocorre ai?

Comment: @LuizNegrini Confira se a nova página possui todas as referências JS que as demais. Pode estar faltando alguma biblioteca.

Comment: sim eu vi isto, porém, uso um editor de texto conhecido que é o TinyMce. No campo de descrição do meu Model, ele é referenciado desta forma: [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml] .... Porém as validações estão funcionando, mas a caixa de edição de texto não carrega mais. Se eu abrir a página sózinha, carrega normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Tal como indicado na mensagem de erro, a tua vista tem como modelo um objecto da classe `BraveryBranded.ASP.Models.News` mas aparentemente estarás a passar um `List<BraveryBranded.ASP.Models.News>`.

Valida se o teu controlador está a passar o objecto correcto ou se a definição da tua vista que agrega ambas não deveria ser `@model IEnumerable<BraveryBranded.ASP.Models.News>`.

Nota que o método RenderPage tem a possibilidade de receber o modelo da vista como parâmetro, por exemplo `@RenderPage("~/Areas/Admin/Views/News/List.cshtml", new BraveryBranded.ASP.Models.News[]{ Model } )`

Comment: A lista eu consegui fazer funcionar se deixa-la sozinha com o seguinte trecho de código: @RenderPage("~/Areas/Admin/Views/News/List.cshtml", new object[]{ Model } )")


Porém quando insiro @RenderPage("~/Areas/Admin/Views/News/New.cshtml") 
aparece um erro dizendo o seguinte: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BraveryBranded.ASP.Models.News]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'BraveryBranded.ASP.Models.News'.

Comment: Podes colocar, sff, o código do controlador que invoca a vista principal?

Comment: alterei a pergunta, esta no último bloco.

Comment: ta no último bloco de código do post.